# ¿Como crear una lista con los valores que ocupan las posiciones pares de una lista ya dada?

Tags: python, lista

El ejercicio me pide que la función imprima una lista nueva con los valores de L que ocupen las posiciones pares, no se si esta bien o no culaquier ayuda la agradezco.

```py
def recorrer_b(L):    
  L = [1,4,3,7,5,9,8,9,3]
  for i in range(0,len(L)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
      L2 = L[i]
      print(L2)
recorrer_b(L)
```

Comment: Por favor has el [tour] y lee [ask] y [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Comment: Si no sabes si está bien, pruebalo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con una comprensión de listas puedes tomar sólo los valores pares:

```
pares = L[1::2]
```

La comprensión tiene tres valores separados por ":".

El primer valor te da el indice inicial. El segundo el indice final y el tercero, el incremento.

La comprensión recorre la lista desde el indice inicial hasta el final (o toda la lista, si no lo colocas.

**Demo**

```
L = [1, 4, 3, 7, 5, 9, 8, 9, 3]
pares = L[1::2]
print(pares)
```

produce:

```
[4, 7, 9, 9]

Process finished with exit code
```

Comment: y si la lista fuera mas larga como puedo modificar el código para que siga sirviendo?

Comment: @arcangeljimenez No necesita ninguna ajuste. Como no indicas el último indice en la comprensión, Python recorre hasta el final de la lista.